# Turn RPi3 Wi-Fi adapter into monitor mode using airmon-ng

Tags: linux, wifi, monitoring, aircrack-ng, raspberry-pi

For some reason, I can't turn the built-in Wi-Fi adapter on the new Raspberry Pi 3 into monitor mode like I used to do on other platforms.

First I kill the processes that interfere with `sudo airmon-ng check kill`:

```
Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID     Name
364     avahi-daemon
385     avahi-daemon
411     wpa_supplicant
629     dhcpcd
Process with PID 411 (wpa_supplicant) is running on interface wlan0
Killing all those processes...
```

Then I try to enable monitor mode with `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`:

```
Interface       Chipset         Driver

wlan0           Unknown         brcmfmac_sdio - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

                                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

The output says it's enabled, but I can't use `mon0`.
How can I fix this and turn the adapter into monitor mode?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot. Not all chipsets/wifi drivers support monitor mode. Broadcom is known for lacking in open source drivers functionality support.

It is already public knowledge the RPi 3 current driver implementation does not support monitor mode.

[PSA: The Raspberry Pi 3's embedded WiFi card does not support promiscuous mode.](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/4ah4oi/psa_the_raspberry_pi_3s_embedded_wifi_card_does/)

If you are buying a replacement, do not go for a cheap realtek one, lots of bugs. Buy ralink or atheros, and check first if the chipset (and monitor mode) is well supported by the Linux kernel.

I am personally happy with this 8-10 Euro ralink, bought in Aliexpress: (link dead several times, replaced by the characteristics): 2T2R 300Mbps Dual Band 2.4GHz 5.8GHz-Ralink RT5572N WiFi USB-Adapter

see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter-realtek

Comment: your link is dead unfortunately. Do you mind providing a raw model number to future proof this post?

Comment: Changed for a new one. It is a moving target unfortunately. Will think later on how to improve it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Are both monitor and injection mode supported for that particular chipset you suggested?

Comment: Ralink usually supports monitor mode; injection mode has to be tested; for that it is safer to buy something more expensive, and atheros model known to support it

Answer (score 6):

The default firmware does not allow monitor mode.
The [Nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon) project has patches to enable that.

Comment: Indeed it appears the next project, that surfaced around the end of 2016,  and provides firmware patches, changed the possible answer. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For a better and updated answer look at [this RPi SO answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54660/17798).

> The firmware used in the BCM4339 (Nexus 5) as well as the BCM43438 (RPI3) got a built-in monitor mode.

The point here, is that the Firmware does support a lot of interesting things, but the kernel drivers does not. In addition the awesome [Nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon) security researchers have patched and upgraded both. They also provide PoC code for both *Active Jamming* using the RPi and are currently working on a limited [SDR functionality](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon/issues/171#issuecomment-356584309).